# zxing intent handle in non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, zxing

I would like to Start and Handle ZXing intent in non-Activity class. But I don't know how to catch Result in this class.

This code is typed in Xamarin, but it is not important.

ScannerZXing.cs:

```
Intent intenScanner;

public ScannerZXing()
{
     intentScanner = ScanIntent.GetZXingScanIntent();
}

public override void Scan(Activity current)
{
     //this.StartActivityForResult(this.intentScanner, 0); // error: Java.Lang.NullPointerExceptionn

    //current.StartActivityForResult(this.intentScanner, 0); // OK, but I have to handle result in MainActivity (I don't want it.)
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [Android.Runtime.GeneratedEnumAttribute()] Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent intent)
{
     base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
     //....
}
```

MainClass.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{

     //....         

     var scanner = new ScannerZXing();

     Button btnScan = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnScan);
     btnScan.Click += delegate
     {
          scanner.Scan(this);
     }
     //....
}
```

If I do OnActivityResult in MainActivity, it works. But I want to move Scanning logic to separated class.

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the nuget for zxing.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile

```
    private async Task<string> Scan()
    {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner() { BottomText = "Place red line on QR image to scan", TopText = "Place red line on QR image to scan", CancelButtonText = "Cancel scan", CameraUnsupportedMessage = "Camera not availabe on device" };
        var scanResults = await scanner.Scan();
        return scanresults;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I know about this way, but I would like to prefer intent approach.

Comment: Pretty sure you need OnActivityResult. Even the nuget probably uses an activity it just abstracts it from your code.